# Is there a known algorithm to detect pixels required to assure the continuity of a shape?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pixel, cellular-automata

I am trying to create a program in Javascript to make a small shape evolve randomly in a binary 2D space.

The first rule is that the number of pixels the shape uses remains constant. It's a very small number (currently 9).

The second rule is that all the pixels should remain contiguous (at least by their corner).

At each step, one pixel is randomly removed and moved to a position in contact with the remaining pixels. However, the pixel can be removed only if it doesn't break the continuity of the shape.

In the attached picture, the blue pixels can be moved whereas the red ones cannot.

[image: moving shape 9 pixels]

I don't know how to detect which pixels are mandatory to maintain the continuity. *Is there any known algorithm for that?* The issue seems close to Conway's Game of life but I as far as I know Conway's rules ignore the idea of continuity and don't maintain a constant number of activated cells. I haven't found any suitable cellular automaton algorithm so far.

Comment: Why are most of the pixels in the O-looking shape red? I think one could remove any one of those pixels and it would still be continuous. What makes the top left pixel special? Also you talk about "moving": it's possible to move one of the red pixels if you move it to a position that re-connects the now "floating" pixels. Do you consider that acceptable? In other words: must the removal alone be valid or only the result of the whole move operation?

Comment: And as a general note: all celluar automatons that I know only consider a small area around each individual cell for their rule. To make a maximally flexible version of what you describe, that wouldn't be sufficien (since two pixels might be connected via a long path that's not "visible" with such a small view-port). Do you aim to write a "proper" cellular automaton or just something that looks visually similar?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer you are right all the pixels in the O-looking shape should be blue. I was just about to replace the picture with a corrected set of examples when I saw your comment.

Comment: The purpose is only to have an evolving shape, with or without a proper cellular automaton.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a custom flood fill and count, if the result is not 9, then you have broken the shape.

Comment: Can you elaborate @Keith?

Comment: @nesdnuma  I'll see if I can explain in more detail with answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints for the shape are very simple, if moving a pixel breaks the shape then it an invalid move.

Because we know the size is always 9 pixels in size, you can confirm if a shape is valid by counting the number of pixels if say you did a floodfill on it, while counting the number pixels filled.

So breaking this down into stages.

1. Pick a random pixel that's part of the shape.
2. Pick another random pixel that's part of the shape that is not the same as first.
3. Move random pixel.
4. Use a custom floodfill algorithm starting at the pixel got at 2.  While filling the shape count the number of pixels filled.
5. If the number of pixels filled is not equal to 9, then moving the pixel was an invalid move. revert back to the original.

Below is an example, there is certainly places it could be optimised, but it should be a good starting point.

UPDATE:
To handle multiple shapes, and prevent them merging, this will also work.  Just a small mod is required, during the fill make sure that the pixel you moved is also included.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 20;
canvas.height = 10;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

let i = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const pp = (x,y) => (x + (y*canvas.width)) * 4;

function putpixel(x, y, t) {
  const s = pp(x,y);
  i.data[s] = t ? 255 : 0;
  i.data[s + 3] = t ? 255 : 0;
}

function getpixel(x, y) {
  const s = pp(x,y);
  return i.data[s] === 255;
}
  
  

for (let y = 0; y < 3; y += 1) 
  for (let x = 0; x < 3; x += 1)
    putpixel(x + 4,y + 4,true);
//let add 2 shapes, still work?    
for (let y = 0; y < 3; y += 1) 
  for (let x = 0; x < 3; x += 1)
    putpixel(x,y,true);



ctx.putImageData(i, 0, 0);

function findPixel(active) {
  while (true) {
    const x = Math.trunc(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    const y = Math.trunc(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    const p = getpixel(x,y);
    if (p === active) return {x,y, p:y*canvas.width + x};
  }
}


function isValid(p, p2) {
  let count = 0; 
  let hit = false;
  const done = {};
  function fill(x, y) {
    const pstr = `${x}:${y}`;
    if (done[pstr]) return;
    if (x < 0) return;
    if (x >= canvas.width) return;
    if (y < 0) return;
    if (y >= canvas.height) return;
    if (!getpixel(x, y)) return;
    count += 1;
    
    if (!hit) {
      if (p2.x === x && p2.y === y) hit = true;
    }
    
    done[pstr] = true;
    fill(x -1, y - 1);
    fill(x   , y - 1);
    fill(x +1, y - 1);
    
    fill(x -1, y);
    fill(x +1, y);
    
    fill(x -1, y + 1);
    fill(x   , y + 1);
    fill(x +1, y + 1);   
  }
  fill(p.x, p.y);
  return count === 9 && hit;
}
    
function evolve() {
  i = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  const movePixel = findPixel(true);
  const otherPixel = findPixel(true);
  if (movePixel.p !== otherPixel.p) {
    const rndPixel = findPixel(false);
    putpixel(movePixel.x, movePixel.y, false);
    putpixel(rndPixel.x ,rndPixel.y, true);
    if (isValid(otherPixel, rndPixel))  
      ctx.putImageData(i, 0, 0);
  }
  setTimeout(evolve, 0);
}


setTimeout(evolve, 0);
```

```css
* { 
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  transform: scale(19);
  image-rendering: pixelated; 
}
```

```html
<canvas>
</canvas>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't require to convert the shape into a graph, which is nice.

Comment: @nesdnuma: Technically, neither does the cut point finding algorithm mentioned by Andrew Vershinin. Or, rather, your shape is already a graph — the pixels in it are the vertices, and you already know how to find the neighbors of a pixel, which is all the algorithm needs.

Answer (score 5):

These are called *cut points* or *articulation points*, and yes, there is an [algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/graph-articulation-points) to find them.

Comment: Ok but that algorithm can not be implement by cellular automaton rule, it breaks locally principle.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès What locality you're talking about if he moves pixels around randomly?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin verifying if a graph is connex cannot be a "local" rule...